# Translation issue

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I have problem with the i18n translation module; despite I translate a text menu link in the administration string translation section, it doesn't translate on the front end when I navigate the site with the other language and it happens for every translated text.

Am I missing anything?

[image: screenshot #1]

[image: screenshot #2]

[image: screenshot #3]

[image: screenshot #3]

Answer (score 1):

Probably not - i18n is notoriously flaky, I find. All I can suggest is you try a bunch of cache clearing, deleting and re-creating of items and see if you can make something stick. Maybe leave that menu item and create another one and see if it translates ok. I think you're experiencing a sort of known issue that is difficult to track down. I've certainly seen this behaviour before and just had to work around it. =(